# Upload a wheel to private PyPi using curl

Tags: python, pypi

I have a wheel built on MS Windows running in a very restricted environment, (cannot connect to internet).  I can copy it to my machine running Linux.  Then, I'd like to upload it to private PyPi.

I don't want to use `twine`.  I had too much bad experience with Python infrastructure tools, so would like to avoid them as much as possible, but if this is not reason enough for you, think about it as "learning experience": I just really want to know what API do I need to use in order to put a file on PyPi server.

---

To spare you some more effort: https://pypiserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ I also read this, and there's no useful info here as well.
The only thing I could find in terms of documentation is this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/ which is useless for my case.

---

This is the closest I've gotten so far: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/distutils/command/upload.py#L92 though it still leaves a lot to be desired, as in: what fields are actually necessary and the restrictions on the contents of the fields.

Comment: What's the advantage of a private pypi server over just keeping your package in a private git server? pip can install straight from git.

Comment: @Dan versioning.  When you download from Git repository, you need to tell setuptools what version of package do you think you are downloading, and since it's all manual labor... you get it wrong too often to be happy.  PS. I would strongly recommend against using `pip` for installing anything: far too many bugs that don't get any resolution in years.